# ES6 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm returning a `Promise` from this function

```
const liab_config = () => {
  return axios.get(`${config.server_url}/fetch_config_liab`);
}

export default { liab_config }
```

And trying to handle the `Promise` inside another file

```
import liab_config from './utils/kc-adapter'

function set_liab_config(){
  liab_config().then((response) => {
    if(response.data.success){
      let { kc_config_liab } = response.data;
      return kc_config_liab['auth-server-url'];
    }
    else
      return null;
  }).catch(ex => 
    console.log(ex));
  }
```

Here I'm getting the error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

on line `liab_config().then((response)`. What could be the reason?

Comment: `export default liab_config`

Comment: Should be `import {liab_config} from './utils/kc-adapter'`

Comment: @TanDuong export default means I can import without {}

Comment: But I saw that you want to export object `export default { liab_config }`.

Comment: yes that is the issue i guess

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're default-exporting an object literal. You want to use either a named export

```
const liab_config = …;
export { liab_config as liab_config }
// shorter:
const liab_config = …;
export { liab_config }
// or just:
export const liab_config = …;
```

with

```
import { liab_config } from './utils/kc-adapter'
```

or a default export

```
const liab_config = …;
export { liab_config as default }
// or just:
default export const liab_config = …;
// or without the local name:
default export …;
```

with

```
import liab_config from './utils/kc-adapter'
```

Answer (score 6):

When you are accessing something like this

`import liab_config from './utils/kc-adapter'`

It means you are asking for the default export which must be written like

```
const liab_config = () => {
  return axios.get(`${config.server_url}/fetch_config_liab`);
}

export { liab_config as default };
```

or like this

```
const liab_config = () => {
  return axios.get(`${config.server_url}/fetch_config_liab`);
}

export default liab_config;
```

And if you don't want to make it default then pass it like

```
export const liab_config = () => {
  return axios.get(`${config.server_url}/fetch_config_liab`);
}
```

or

```
const liab_config = () => {
  return axios.get(`${config.server_url}/fetch_config_liab`);
}

export { liab_config };
```

And access it like

```
import {liab_config} from './utils/kc-adapter'
```